# Using mingw-w64 and ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32.static, make fails and Makefile CC variable looks wrong

Tags: makefile, configure, mingw-w64, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to compiling.

I am trying to compile iperf3 for Windows 10 because there is no official Windows distribution of iperf3 and for the learning experience.  I am trying to do so on the new Windows Subsystem for Linux feature via Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, also for the learning experience.

I installed mingw-w64, which should give me the proper compiler and environment necessary for cross-compiling:
`sudo apt-get install mingw-w64`

This put two directories into my `/usr` directory:
`i686-w64-mingw32`
`x86_64-w64-mingw32`

It also put a bunch of things that look like compilers into `/usr/bin`.

I unzipped the `.tar.gz` file from iperf3 and navigated into it.  Then, I run `./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32.static` and it completes without errors.

I note that the output of the command has a worrisome line: `checking for i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc... no`

I note that the `Makefile`'s `CC` variable is set to `gcc`, which doesn't sound like the proper compiler.

Then, I run `make`.  It fails with errors:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [iperf3] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/snip/iperf3/iperf-3.1.4/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/snip/iperf3/iperf-3.1.4/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I also see the line: `libtool: warning: undefined symbols not allowed in i686-w64-mingw32.static shared libraries; building static only`

I think that the `./configure` is not working correctly since it appears to have not found the right compiler for my `--host` argument and put it in the `Makefile`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I changed the command to `./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32` per comments and it completes without error. But no makefile is created so `make` yields `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

What am I doing wrong, now?

EDIT 2:
Looks like the `./configure` actually is failing.  Last line of its output is `nanosleep() required for timing operations.`, which seems to mean that its missing a library for nanosleep.

How do I get nanosleep?

Comment: it should be `--host=i686-w64-mingw32`

Comment: @StevenPenny, thanks for your input.  I have done this and no Makefile is created.  Please see edit.  Would appreciate further advice.

Comment: @Shaun Any progress on your side since then?

Answer (score 0):

`mingw` doesn't support nanosleep.  So programs using it cannot be compiled using `mingw-w64`.

Comment: Or maybe not?  This sure looks like nanosleep.
https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/4f636f370f879769c267012944d9c7fffd9756aa/tree/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads/src/nanosleep.c